# Duplicate datas across tables keeping referencies IDs

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm asking your opinion to know if this is possible, because I'm noob and maybe I'm trying to do it in a complete wrong way. I've searched a lot but found nothing, maybe not using correct search criteria.
I'm using Postgresql 9.1. I have simplified the situation to understand the method

I have 3 tables:

- table A (the master)
- table B (linked to table A)
- table C (linked to table B)

(see the schema)

Table A

```
    id_A | data_A
    -----+--------
     A01 | dataA01
     A02 | dataA02
```

Table B

```
    id_B | ref_id_A | data_B
    -----+----------+--------
     B01 |    A01   | dataB01
     B02 |    A01   | dataB02
     B03 |    A02   | dataB03
     B04 |    A02   | dataB04
     B05 |    A02   | dataB05
     B06 |    A02   | dataB06
```

Table C

```
    id_C | ref_id_B | data_C
    -----+----------+--------
     C01 |    B01   | dataC01
     C02 |    B01   | dataC02
     C03 |    B02   | dataC03
     C04 |    B02   | dataC04
```

What I'm trying to do is to duplicate all the data linked to table A, keeping all the data and referencies that are stored in table B and C with the new IDs. It should work like a copy and paste, to maintain old versions while working on new

Duplicate A01 -> A03

Table A

```
    id_A | data_A
    -----+--------
     A01 | dataA01
     A02 | dataA02
     A03 | dataA01
```

Table B

```
    id_B | ref_id_A | data_B
    -----+----------+--------
     B01 |    A01   | dataB01
     B02 |    A01   | dataB02
     B03 |    A02   | dataB03
     B04 |    A02   | dataB04
     B05 |    A02   | dataB05
     B06 |    A02   | dataB06
     B07 |    A03   | dataB01
     B08 |    A03   | dataB02
```

Table C

```
    id_C | ref_id_B | data_C
    -----+----------+--------
     C01 |    B01   | dataC01
     C02 |    B01   | dataC02
     C03 |    B02   | dataC03
     C04 |    B02   | dataC04
     C05 |    B07   | dataC01
     C06 |    B07   | dataC02
     C07 |    B08   | dataC03
     C08 |    B08   | dataC04
```

I wrote this query to duplicate A01 and it keeps perfectly data in table B, but I'm not able to duplicate data in table C

```
WITH new_id_A as 
(insert into table_A (id_A, data_A) (select id_A, data_A from table_A where id_A='A01') returning id_A) 
 insert into table_B (ref_id_A, data_B) select (select id_A from new_id_A) as ref_id_A, data_B from table_B where ref_id_A='A01';
```

I tried different approaches, but with no results
I can accomplish the task easy using code, but I'd prefer to complete it inside then database in a single transaction
Thanks for your attention

Comment: How do you generate IDs in tables? Ideally that would be done sequence. In that case inserting 'Copy' of data should not be difficult.

Comment: You could write a trigger to update `Table B` with the new ID when `Table A` gets changed.

Comment: @Bulat IDs are serial autoincremental, no way to change the table structure to store alphanumeric IDs without changing all the tables. But it is a good idea if I'll make a new db

Comment: @Colin I do not understand very well your suggestion about trigger. Are you saying that I should make a trigger that when I add a new row in table A it should copy a record? Which record? How to specify Which record? Maybe I need a function

Comment: Using the approach of the query I wrote before the problem is that I can report new ID of table B, but data in table C are related to old ID_B. So I need a table with old_id_1 -> new_id_1 to retrieve data from table C

Comment: I think you just need to store IDs of copied A records in a temporary table  `(old_id, new_id)` and apply same approach to both B and C selecting ID's from that temp table.

Comment: A function would be a better approach from my original comment yes, but basically when it fires to copy the record from `Table A` it just updates the `ref_id_A` in `Table B` where `ref_id_A` equals the original row ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stage IDs for new rows in temporary table like this for simplicity:

```
WITH new_id_A as 
(insert into table_A (id_A, data_A) (select id_A, data_A from table_A where id_A='A01') returning id_A) 
SELECT 'A01' AS old_id, id_A AS new_id
INSERT INTO TEMP table_A_copy;

insert into table_B (ref_id_A, data_B) 
select cp.new_id, b.data_B
from 
 table_A_copy cp INNER JOIN
 table_B b ON b.ref_id_A = cp.old_id;

insert into table_C (ref_id_B, data_B) 
select b_new.id_B, c.data_C 
from 
 table_A_copy cp INNER JOIN
 table_b b_old on b_old.ref_id_a = cp.old_id inner join 
 table_b b_new on b_new.ref_id_a = cp.new_id inner join 
 table_C c ON c.ref_id_B = b_old.id_B;
```

Update from Fabio:

```
drop table if exists table_a_copy; 
create temp table table_a_copy ("old_id" integer, "new_id" integer); 

with new_id_a as 
(insert into table_a (data_a) 
  (select data_a from table_a where id_a='1') returning id_a) 
 insert into table_a_copy select '1'::integer as old_id, 
  (select * from new_id_a) as new_id; 

-- Insert to table B
insert into table_b (ref_id_a, data_b) 
select cp.new_id, b.data_b 
from 
  table_a_copy cp inner join 
  table_b b on b.ref_id_a = cp.old_id;

-- Insert to table C
insert into table_c (ref_id_B, data_C) 
select b_new.id_b, c.data_c 
from 
  table_a_copy cp inner join 
  table_b b_old on b_old.ref_id_a = cp.old_id inner join 
  table_b b_new on b_new.ref_id_a = cp.new_id inner join 
  table_c c on c.ref_id_b = b_old.id_b;
```

Comment: Tried your code, but not working, problems making temp table from select. So, changed the code to build before the temp table, then putting data inside. Also problem with last line of query `table_C c ON b.ref_id_C = c.id_C `, seems to me should be `table_C c ON c.ref_id_B = b.id_B`. In this way query works, but data copied in table_C are not correctly referred to table_B

Comment: Here the query I used, splitted to avoid comment character limit

Comment: `drop table if exists table_a_copy;
create temp table table_a_copy ("old_id" integer, "new_id" integer);
with new_id_a as 
(insert into table_a (data_a) (select data_a from table_a where id_a='1') returning id_a) 
insert into table_a_copy select '1'::integer as old_id, (select * from new_id_a) as new_id;

insert into table_b (ref_id_a, data_b) 
select cp.new_id, b.data_b
from 
 table_a_copy cp inner join
 table_b b on b.ref_id_a = cp.old_id;`

Comment: `insert into table_c (ref_id_b, data_c)  
select b.id_b, c.data_c 
from 
 table_a_copy cp inner join
 table_b b on b.ref_id_a = cp.old_id inner join
 table_c c on c.ref_id_b = b.id_b;`

Comment: @FabioSoggia sorry there was a typo in last query. Did it work in the end for you?

Comment: sorry, no, it doesn't work. Records inserted into table C are not correctly linked to table B, they refer to old_id_B instead of new_id_B

Comment: You are right, I have updated my answer. You need to link to `B` records via `new_id` field.

Comment: With this change, no record is inserted into table C

Comment: Sorry, error in db <br/>`ERROR:  column "b_new" of relation "table_c" does not exist<br/>
LINE 18: insert into table_c (b_new.id_B, data_c) select`

Comment: Now data in table C are duplicated, with references to B lost (b1 owns c1 and c2; b2 owns c3 and c4 - now b1_dup owns c1_dup, c2_dup, c3_dup, c4_dup: b2_dup owns c1_dup, c2_dup, c3_dup, c4_dup)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final query after the tests I made. It seems to me to work perfectly, but I think it should be replace by a simpler method
Please add your opinion or correction, thanks

```
drop table if exists table_old_id_a;  
drop table if exists table_new_id_a;  
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_a;  
-- 3 table  
-- 1st with old IDs and an arbitrary column to use to join
-- 2nd with new IDs after insert; you just need the ID to avoid that other use the same ID, insert only minimum data
-- 3rd is a table where you join old and new IDs using the join_column sequence
-- after this you must update table_a with all the data you need, but you keep references in temp table table_joined_old_new_id_a
create temp table table_old_id_a ("join_column" serial, "old_id" integer);
create temp table table_new_id_a ("join_column" serial, "new_id" integer);
create temp table table_joined_old_new_id_a ("old_id" integer, "new_id" integer);
insert into table_old_id_a (old_id) select id_a from table_a where id_a='1';
with new_id_a as
(insert into table_a (data_a) (select 'Copy of ' || data_a from table_a where id_a='1') returning id_a) 
insert into table_new_id_a (new_id) select id_a from new_id_a;
insert into table_joined_old_new_id_a select table_old_id_a.old_id, table_new_id_a.new_id from table_old_id_a, table_new_id_a where table_old_id_a.join_column=table_new_id_a.join_column;
-- then update the table with all the data
with t_update_a as (select data_a, new_id, data_a2 from table_a t_old_id, table_joined_old_new_id_a where t_old_id.id_a=table_joined_old_new_id_a.old_id)
update table_a set 
data_a=(select data_a from t_update_a where table_a.id_a=t_update_a.new_id),
data_a2=(select data_a2 from t_update_a where table_a.id_a=t_update_a.new_id)
where table_a.id_a in (select new_id from table_joined_old_new_id_a);
-- table B data
drop table if exists table_old_id_b;
drop table if exists table_new_id_b;
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_b;
create temp table table_old_id_b ("join_column" serial, "old_id" integer);
create temp table table_new_id_b ("join_column" serial, "new_id" integer);
create temp table table_joined_old_new_id_b ("old_id" integer, "new_id" integer);
insert into table_old_id_b (old_id) select id_b from table_b where ref_id_a in (select old_id from table_old_id_a);
with new_id_b as 
(insert into table_b (data_b) (select 'Copy of ' || data_b from table_b, table_old_id_a where table_old_id_a.old_id=table_b.ref_id_a) returning id_b)
insert into table_new_id_b (new_id) select id_b from new_id_b;
insert into table_joined_old_new_id_b select table_old_id_b.old_id, table_new_id_b.new_id from table_old_id_b, table_new_id_b where table_old_id_b.join_column=table_new_id_b.join_column;
-- then update the table with all the data
with t_update_b as  
(select data_b, new_id, ref_id_a from table_b t_old_id, table_joined_old_new_id_b where t_old_id.id_b=table_joined_old_new_id_b.old_id)
update table_b set 
ref_id_a=(select table_joined_old_new_id_a.new_id from table_joined_old_new_id_a, t_update_b where table_joined_old_new_id_a.old_id=t_update_b.ref_id_a and table_b.id_b=t_update_b.new_id),
data_b=(select data_b from t_update_b where table_b.id_b=t_update_b.new_id)
where table_b.id_b in (select new_id from table_joined_old_new_id_b);
-- table C data
drop table if exists table_old_id_c;
drop table if exists table_new_id_c;
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_c;
create temp table table_old_id_c ("join_column" serial, "old_id" integer);
create temp table table_new_id_c ("join_column" serial, "new_id" integer);
create temp table table_joined_old_new_id_c ("old_id" integer, "new_id" integer);
insert into table_old_id_c (old_id) select id_c from table_c where ref_id_b in (select old_id from table_old_id_b);
with new_id_c as 
(insert into table_c (data_c) (select 'Copy of ' || data_c from table_c, table_old_id_b where table_old_id_b.old_id=table_c.ref_id_b) returning id_c)
insert into table_new_id_c (new_id) select id_c from new_id_c;
insert into table_joined_old_new_id_c select table_old_id_c.old_id, table_new_id_c.new_id from table_old_id_c, table_new_id_c where table_old_id_c.join_column=table_new_id_c.join_column;
-- then update the table with all the data
with t_update_c as  
(select data_c, new_id, ref_id_b from table_c t_old_id, table_joined_old_new_id_c where t_old_id.id_c=table_joined_old_new_id_c.old_id)
update table_c set 
ref_id_b=(select table_joined_old_new_id_b.new_id from table_joined_old_new_id_b, t_update_c where table_joined_old_new_id_b.old_id=t_update_c.ref_id_b and table_c.id_c=t_update_c.new_id),
data_c=(select data_c from t_update_c where table_c.id_c=t_update_c.new_id)
where table_c.id_c in (select new_id from table_joined_old_new_id_c);
-- last drop the temp tables
drop table if exists table_old_id_a;
drop table if exists table_new_id_a;
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_a;
drop table if exists table_old_id_b;
drop table if exists table_new_id_b;
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_b;
drop table if exists table_old_id_c;
drop table if exists table_new_id_c;
drop table if exists table_joined_old_new_id_c;
-- Finish!
```

Comment: During my test I add a column (data_a2) to table_A in order to have more data to test the correct copy, so it is different from the initial schema I posted